# How to get around the lack of abstract fields in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class, field

Assume, we have an abstract class `A` and we want to force all subclasses to have a certain field. This is not possible in Java, because we can not define abstract fields.

**Workaround 1:** Force subclasses to implement a method which delivers the wanted value.

```
abstract class A {
  abstract int getA();
}
```

*Drawback*: Each subclass has to implement a method for each abstract field we want to have. This can lead to many method implementations.

*Advantage*: We can use the method `getA` in the abstract class and implement methods with it in `A` without implementing them in each subclass. But the value behind the method can not be overwritten by the abstract class.

**Workaround 2:** Simulate the abstract field by forcing the subclass to give the abstract class a value.

```
abstract class A {
  int a;

  public A(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

*Drawback*: When we have multiple fields (> 10), the super constructor call will look a bit ugly and confusing.

*Advantage*: We can use the field `a` in the abstract class and implement methods with it in `A` without implementing them in each subclass. Plus, the value `a` can be overwritten by the abstract class.

**Question:** Which workaround is the common way to reach the goal ? Maybe there is a better one than the above ones ?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not simply give the abstract class a protected *concrete* field? Why the desire for an "*abstract*" field? What is an abstract field to begin with? Again, what am I missing or not understanding? Am I over-simplifying your problem? And what behavioral problem (not code problem) are you trying to solve anyway?

Comment: Or you can provide a default implementation of `getA()` and just override it where you want another value.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to force all subclasses to have a field?  The problem is generally better formulated in terms of forcing them to have a specific _behavior_, which you just do with method specifications.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract method is probably the most object oriented.

If you have too many fields, you may want to regroup those in a POJO (if a new concept is appropriate).

Comment: nice feature is that a might not even exist: int getA(){return 4;} if property a always 4 for the subclass or getA(){return b +c;} if it depends on other fields.

Comment: Make it a generic method and not only could it possibly not exist, it's type might not yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first one . i dont love to couple classes in fileds name , how they handle state and how they save it. the first one is more close to [open/close principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

I recommend to avoid inheritance. inheritance is very frigle and hard to maintenance. remember effective java advice  - prefer composition other inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I think opt.1 is the cleaner by far. A few getters and setters is not a big deal, and I doubt that many use cases would have more than just a few abstract "fields".

About opt.2, you forget that constructors are not inherited, and thus would require all sub classes constructors to be implemented in a way that takes `a` into account.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround 2 is very common because of 2 advantages:

1) the one you mentioned - the field does not belong to the subclass - it belongs to the parent and that is important because it was "demanded" by the parent and because the parent can use it

2) When sub-classing from the parent you are very aware of this field because when you implement the constructor you must pass it on. If I saw the first workaround I wouldn't know what to understand from it, in this way I understand that the parent class needs this field to work, so it must have a meaningful value.

note: if you have a class that has 10 fields that need to be initialized something is probably wrong in your design.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Actually its not about what one prefers but its about the **flexibility, and the ability 
       to adapt changes**.

**2.** Its always better to **Encapsulate Behaviors that keeps changing, either into an Interface or Abstract class.**

**3.** You **1st Workaround** will be good in places where you **need different implementation for the same Behavior in Different classes**. Then at this place either an **Interface** or your **1st Workaround** will be a good choice.

**Eg:**

Consider `Painting` as a Class with `paint()` Method.

Now

`paint()` method can have Stroking, gliding, shading etc styles of doing it.

**Then its better to Encapsulate that method into an Abstract class or an Interface.**

```
public interface Paint{

paintDoIt(String style);

}
```

**4.** Your **2nd Wordaround** will be good in a place, **where you want certain behaviors to be MUST implemented by the Subclass.**

Eg:

Consider **Car as an Abstract Class**, Now `to be car` its very important that **it must have
   a Steering, 4 wheels, Engine, etc. So these features must be implemented**.

where as **other features like music system, LCD ,etc are optional** and depends on the car type.